# Map function in D3, confused about multiple functions passed in

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This example from Mike Bostock:

https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/34f08d5e11952a80609169b7917d4172

The following line confuses me and i was wondering if someone could clear it up.

```
x.domain(s.map(x2.invert, x2));
```

Why is `x2` being passed in as a second argument? As far as I know the second parameter is the optional `thisArg` argument, but as `invert` doesn't need it why's it being passed in? The code seems to work fine without it so what am I missing?

Comment: I think you are right assuming that the second argument is not needed in this case. Sifting through the code I can't seem to find any reference to `this` and the example will run just fine if you remove it. But, as this happens only rarely in Mike Bostock's examples, I am going to curiously follow this ;-)

Comment: Ye thats my understanding too, and as you say as this is Mike Bostock i figured i was definitely missing something but maybe it is just a rare bit of redundant code.

Comment: @altocumulus and Mike, I like questions like these because, despite the fact that the answer (if any) is primarily opinion-based, they are *little puzzles*: why is that piece of code that way? Does it have any purpose? Is it something Bostock copy/pasted from another code, without paying attention?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I totally agree with that! I even checked the github revision history of both the Block/gist as well as the `.invert()` method for any clues, yet to no avail. It's these questions that teach you the most about JS in general and D3 in particular.

Comment: @altocumulus I have a supposition, which unfortunately is just this: a supposition. Have a look below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question can finally be settled as Mike Bostock thankfully reacted to GitHub issue [#173 *Simplify / clarify rescaleX and rescaleY.*](https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom/issues/173):

> The answer is: it’s good practice in JavaScript. If the object’s methods happen to be bound to the object, it’s unnecessary to specify *this*, but one generally shouldn’t assume so unless it is documented (and not likely to change in a future version).

Answer (score 1):

(*edit*: well, my supposition ended up being wrong, see the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56690681/5768908))

---

Two years after this very interesting question was posted I had a glimpse of the probable solution to this mystery. However, a good deal of supposition remains: only Mike Bostock, the author of that code, has the real answer (provided that he still remembers why he did it that way).

As OP mentioned, this `thisArg` in the `map` function is irrelevant:

```
x.domain(s.map(x2.invert, x2));
//this bit here -----------^
```

That's because the `invert` method of the scale needs no `this` value.

However, if we look some dozen lines further down at that same code, we'll find this:

```
context.select(".brush").call(brush.move, x.range().map(t.invertX, t));
```

And here we find `thisArg` again:

```
x.range().map(t.invertX, t)
//thisArg ---------------^
```

The reason for this, if we look at the [source code](https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom/blob/6f8b119399f1b68183974ae818b9900514a24df0/src/transform.js#L27) for `invertX`, is that `invertX` needs a value to use as `this`:

```
invertX: function(x) {
    return (x - this.x) / this.k;
}
```

And here comes my supposition: `invert` and `invertX` are quite similar names and, even despite Bostock had invented them and had written countless D3 codes, he confused the two and set the `thisArg` for `x2.invert`, which although being unnecessary didn't break the code, and went unnoticed by the author.

One extra argument in favour of this supposition is that, in both cases, he used the object as the `thisArg`. Compare:

```
x2.invert, x2
|          |
t.invertX, t
```